# How do I digitally sign emails outgoing from different identities?

Tags: thunderbird, email, certificates, smtp, signature

To send emails, I use one SMTP server, say *domain1.com*. But I use two identities that set up in Thunderbird, say *agmenor@domain1.com* and *agmenor@domain2.com*. For those who are not knowledgeable about it, this means that my addressees see emails coming from  agmenor@domain1.com and from agmenor@domain2.com, with no evident link between the two.
Furthermore, I was issued a SMIME certificate for each identity from an authority, in the form of a .p12 file. This permits me to digitally sign my emails.

How do I set up Thunderbird so that it signs my outgoing emails with the correct certificate respectively to each identity?
The problem I now face is that I know only how to associate my SMTP server to a certificate, but not to each identity separately.

Answer (score 1):

You assign the certificates to each email account by selecting the security option in Account Settings and then selecting proper certificates.

However, if both signing certificates have the same name (for example your name), you will not be able to use both because of this 7 year old and never fixed bug in Thunderbird:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=278689